# JavaScript font color change based on user input

Tags: javascript, html

so I have this little temperature converter.
All I want is to change the temp **font color to red** when is higher than 30 (e.g.), and I can't to get this work. I would be obliged for any help.

```js
function colorChange(myVal) {
  var myVal = document.getElementById("fahrenheit").value;
  if (myVal > 30) {
    document.getElementById("fahrenheit").style.color = "red";
  }
}
colorChange();
```

```html
<input type="number" id="inputCelsius" placeholder="Enter Celsius" oninput="myFunction(this.value)" onchange="myFunction(this.value)" />
<p>Fahrenheit: <span id="fahrenheit"></span></p>
<p>Kelvin: <span id="kelvin"></span></p>
```

Comment: Where's your `myFunction`? Also, you call your `colorchange` function when the page loads instead of onchange

Comment: Also be sure to reset the color if the temperature drops

Comment: myFunction is for another function...

function myFunction(valNum) {
  fahr = "℉";
  kelv = "K";

  valNum = parseFloat(valNum);

  document.getElementById("kelvin").innerHTML =
    Math.round(valNum + 273.15) + kelv;
  document.getElementById("fahrenheit").innerHTML = Math.round(
    valNum * 1.8 + 32
  );

So where should I put it?
document.getElementById("fahrenheit").onchange = colorChange; -> Still doesn't work.

Comment: You may be recieving the number as string insetead of a number, you can user parsefloat(myVal)

Comment: if you set onchange in javascript it erases what you set for the onchange in the html. you can only have one onchnage. you need to use addEventListener to add more than one event handler.. or just call the second function at the bottom of the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onchage` event to call the action when input is changed

```js
function hola(){
  let elem = document.getElementById('my-id')
  if(elem.value > 30){
      elem.style.color = 'red'
  }else{
          
      elem.style.color = 'black'

  }
  
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="whatever" id="my-id" onchange="hola()"></input>
```

If you use `oninput` the result will be the same, but the function will be triggered every time you type